# Java - Returning function with parameters

Tags: java, lambda

I just started to learn about the lambda functions in Java. And wondering if this is the proper way of create a "adder".

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Function<Integer, Integer> fiveAdder = adder(5);
        System.out.println(fiveAdder.apply(1)); //6
        System.out.println(fiveAdder.apply(2)); //7
        Function<Integer, Integer> tenAdder = adder(10);
        System.out.println(tenAdder.apply(1)); //11
        System.out.println(tenAdder.apply(2)); //12
        System.out.println(fiveAdder.apply(1)); //6
        System.out.println(fiveAdder.apply(2)); //7
    }

    public static Function<Integer, Integer> adder(Integer inc){
        return num -> num + inc;
    }
}
```

The code is running fine. But I am not sure if that is the proper way of doing it, or if there is a better way. Like the function part `num -> num + inc` is using `inc` but not some final/static field. (Plus IntelliJ is high-lighting the `inc` for me that makes me suspicious...)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Just changing `inc` to `final` should be enough to get rid of the highlight.

Comment: *IntelliJ is high-lighting the inc*: and what warning message does it display?

Comment: What do you want your "adder" to do ? What is the question here?

Comment: @JBNizet it is showing "Go to supermethod" , and "expand lambda expression body to {...}". Which will change it to `return num -> {return num + inc ;};`

Comment: So there is now warning at all. It just offers you shortcuts to navigate through your code or transform it. So why worry?

Comment: @kennytm I tried to change the signature to `public static Function<Integer, Integer> adder(final Integer inc)` but the high-lighting  is still there.

Comment: @Man-KitYau The highlighting means something else, I think. The two options "Go to supermethod" and "expand lambda expression body to {...}" are not problems of your code. They are just there to help you, if you ever want to do those things.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, your code is pretty fine, but I can't think of any situation in production code where you want to return an adder though...

> Like the function part num -> num + inc is using inc but not some final/static field.

If you made the `inc` parameter `final`, it does not really make a difference. It just prevents you from reassigning `inc` inside the method. Who would ever do that? (except drunk people and people who want to prank you...)

If a function's return value depends on a variable static field, it would be quite weird indeed:

```
someStaticField = 5;
Function<Integer, Integer> adder1 = adder();
```

A function like `adder` should be standalone.

> Plus IntelliJ is high-lighting the inc for me that makes me suspicious...

No it's not (for me):

[image]

It's probably something else, like the highlight you get when you hover over a variable and it shows you all the other places where you used the variable.